# Are all symmetrical real matrices invertible (except $A = 0$)?

Tags: inverse, symmetric-matrices

Assuming that we have a matrix $A$ that is symmetric. Non negative values.
Can this matrix $A$ be non invertible (except for the case $A = 0$) or are all symmetrical matrices invertible, always?

Because if $A$ where non invertible, then $A^TA$ will become invertible. According to my professor.

Comment: Try $\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1}$.

Comment: Are you sure you've heard correctly? Because $$A \text{ is non-invertible} \implies \text{det }(A) = 0 \implies \text{det }(A^TA)=0 \implies A^TA \text{ is non-invertible}$$

Comment: @glowstonetrees i tried that with gnu octave and it works

Comment: Wasn't your teacher alluding to the *pseudo-inverse* ?

Comment: @yvesdaoust perhaps he did. Need to look in the notes now.